# Do votes down on an answer canceled for deleting it?

Tags: feature-request, down-votes, deleted-answers, cancel

I mistakenly answered a question and got voted down. Now, I've learned the lesson, can I delete the answer to cancel the votes (after all, the voting mechanism purpose is to give feedback to the writer, and help the readers to get the right answers)?

Comment: deleting the answer will clear up/down votes.

Comment: Yes, if you delete the answer, the reputation changes you had from votes on it will be nullified. (Might take a few minutes, caching.)

Comment: Thanks! Is it the same for questions votes?

Comment: How about improving the answer to correct the problems? Deleting will return the reputation (the same goes for questions) but if you do it too often you might get answer/question-banned.

Comment: Trying not to do it often... Anyway, other correct answers have already been posted meanwhile. I don't have anything to add...